# use output test case with other test case in input value, RIDE/robot framework

Tags: testing, automation, robotframework, testcase

I have a probelm to use an output from a test case to use it with another test tase like input value ! did you have an idea how to do that ?

Comment: Please show us how you are running the specific test case. It's easy to run just a single test case, so you must be doing something incorrectly. Unless we see what you are doing, we can't help.

Comment: it was a problem with RIDE.

Answer (score 0):

Even I have seen this issue with Ride. Sometimes ride does not save changes. Need to restart ride to see the saved changes. So, I am using ride only for development purpose and using command line to run test cases. On one window edit changes in ride and run test cases on command line.
To run single test case from command line:
python -m robot -t test_case_name test_suite_name

Hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: @Dali This is a different question. You should create a new question, not append to the current  one, even if you created the original one.